# What is corresponding Cron expression to fire in every X seconds, where X > 60?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want my jobs to execute in every X seconds, there's one to one matching between job and X. Also during runtime there can be registered new jobs with their own intervals.

I've tried to write cron expression for such scenarios, but in documentation there's written that value of seconds can't be more than 59. So cron expression like this: "0/63 * * * * ?" isn't valid.

At first sight solution of that problem seemed to be expression like this: "0/3 0/1 * * * ?", but it means completely different thing: trigger job in every three second of every minute.

Can you suggest what is the right solution (cron expression) for that? I know I could use just simple timers, but I've to use cron jobs using Quartz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Quartz cron syntax is designed to express timing based on the standard 24 hour, 60 minute clock. It's not suitable for "every n seconds", where n can be any value. You're not going to able to do this with cron expressions.

If you need to do this with Quartz, you should use `SimpleTrigger`, not `CronTrigger`. You don't really have an option, unless you want to use a hugely complex collection of overlapping, artificially-deduced cron expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that Quartz has SimpleTrigger.